# Show that $f$ is continuous mathematically.

Tags: proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. Show
>   that it is continuous.

This is taken from Example 3.7 on <[link](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch3.pdf)> page 22 on the paper. It has shown that it is continuous at $c=0$ and $c>0$ seperately, which I understood why. I wondered how I would prove it if I got a similar problem from my teacher without showing how I have processed it (that is, how the values of $\delta>0$ were found). I thought about the following way,

> Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and let $c\in [0,\infty)$. Choose
>   $$\delta=\begin{cases} \epsilon^{2} & \text{ if } c=0 \\ 
>  \epsilon\sqrt{c} & \text{ if } c>0. \end{cases}$$ Assume $c=0$. If
>    $\left | x-c \right |=\left | x-0 \right |<\delta$, then $$\left |
>  f(x)-f(c) \right |=\left | \sqrt{x}-0 \right |=\left | x-0 \right
>  |^{1/2}<\delta^{1/2}=\epsilon.$$ Assume $c>0$. If $\left | x-c \right
>  |<\delta$, then $$\left | f(x)-f(c) \right |= \left |
>  \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c} \right |=\left | \frac{x-c}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}}
>  \right |\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\left | x-c \right |
>  <\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\delta=\epsilon.$$ This proves that $f$ is
>   continuous.

Is this correct, or is there a better way to show it mathematically?

Comment: Seems good to me.

Comment: @AjmalW: looks fine. OT: what macro did you use to shade your background? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks both of you. Chilango, when making a question, there's a tool below the "Title" how your post should look like. It's a blockquote; press CTRL + Q. It also works when answering a question.

Comment: Looks good to me.  Defining $\delta$ first for both cases is not really necessary but it is fine either way.

Comment: As a slight technicality issue, your choice of $\delta$ should make sure you have positive $x$ values only, since the square root is not defined for negative values. For example, if $\varepsilon = 10$ and $c = 25$, $\delta = 50$. By the definition of continuity, we require $\forall x$ s.t. $|x - 25| < 50$, $|f(x) - 5| < 10$. But $|-10 - 25| = 35 < 50$ and $f(-10)$ is not defined. To fix this, let $\delta = \min\{c, \varepsilon\sqrt{c}\}$. Hope this helps!

Comment: @JairTaylor, what would you do otherwise?

Comment: @Nitin You see, the function is actually defined for all $x\geq 0$ as it's described in the post.  The fix doesn't really work as $c=0$ doesn't make sense, that is, $\delta$ should be positive.

Comment: @AjmalW, you could also just do the two cases separately as in the text.  As I said, either way is okay.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good! About the only tweak that I would suggest is to make use of the fact that $x\mapsto\sqrt x$ is a monotonically increasing function on the nonnegative reals. Do you see why that is relevant in both cases?

Comment: Thanks. Not really. I thought that if there is a value $k$ in the domain such that $f(k)=0$ then the value of $\delta>0$ would be different in this case. For example, if $x\mapsto x^{2}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then there are two values of $\delta>0$. I'd love to know more if there's a reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

As to whether there is a "better" way, it actually seems to me that proving continuity via $\epsilon$-$\delta$ specifically for the square root looks a bit awkward.

There is the elegant argument that the inverse of a bijective continuous function $f$: $[a, b]\longrightarrow f([a, b])$ is continuous, and the general proof sort of writes itself.

Then, applying this to $x\mapsto x^2$ on $[0, r]$, $r>0$, gives the result immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I *really* dislike an answer like this.
It shows that the answerer
has worked through all the cases
and found the
$\delta(\epsilon)$
for each case.
The results then appear
like a magic trick.

I much prefer an answer
where the analysis
is explicitly stated
showing *how*
$\delta(\epsilon)$ is derived.
This will also convince me
that the answerer
really knows
what they are doing.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Whenever I think of the definition of continuity, my goal is to find the value of $\delta>0$ in order to make the condition satisfied. When having found it, I would mention the value of $\delta>0$ without showing how. If I should show how it's derived then the answer would be too long and unorganized. The reason why I think it would be long is because that the process would repeat to check if the condition actually holds after having shown the value of $\delta>0$.